# Ubuntu Server + Window Manager + Network Applet

Tags: server, network-manager, applet

I'm trying to build a minimal desktop system on top of ubuntu server 13.04, and I've got the i3 window manager running.

Apparently the standard nm-applet package is no longer in the ubuntu repos, and when I try to install the network-manager package, apt-get tries to pull down the entire gnome desktop with it, which is no good to me.

So my question is, is anyone aware of any other network manager/indicator applet in the repos that won't require me to pull down an entire desktop environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options. The first is to use a different network manager altogether such as [wicd](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/wicd).
The other option is to install `network-manager` but without installing its recommended packages as this will bring in less dependencies. You can do this with the command:

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends network-manager
```

Answer (score 0):

Try WICD.

> Wicd is an open source wired and wireless network manager for Linux
>   which aims to provide a simple interface to connect to networks with a
>   wide variety of settings.

To install click [**WICD** [image: Install comixcursors-lefthanded]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/wicd-gtk/).

<sup>Source:Wicd</sup>